# How to create an inline keyboard with multiple rows in TelegramBotAPI?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

How can I create an inline keyboard with several buttons, one per row?

like:

```
inlineBtn1
inlineBtn2
inlineBtn3
...
```

not:

```
inlineBtn1  inlineBtn2  inlineBtn3 ...
```

Comment: Please specify the library you're using for the bot ([this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/) or another), and your code which you tried to create the inline keyboard.

Comment: I use telegrambotAPI in nuget pakage manager, i trying but alwase result is 1 row with some buttons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Solved it

```
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "test", replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
    {
        new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton() { Text = "btn 1",CallbackData="Some data1" } }, // buttons in row 1
        new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton() { Text = "btn 2", CallbackData = "Some data2" } }, // buttons in row 2
        new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton() {Text =  "btn 3", CallbackData = "Some data3" } }// buttons in row 3
    }));
```

We must use exactly one of the optional fields.
So you have to pass either url, callback_data or switch_inline_query The button would be useless if you don't pass any of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a chat with an inline keyboard use the `replyMarkup` parameter of `TelegramBot.SendMessage` or `TelegramBot.SendMessageAsync` method. It can be either `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` or `InlineKeyboardMarkup`. A constructor of `InlineKeyboardMarkup` accepts an array of button rows (each of them, in turn, comprises an array of buttons in the given row). To create an inline keyboard with several buttons one per row pass an array with several rows with one element each:

```
TelegramBot bot = ...;
Chat chat = ...;

await bot.SendMessageAsync(chat.Id, "A message. Use the keyboard below.",
    replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
        {
            new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton("inlineBtn1") }, // buttons in row 1
            new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton("inlineBtn2") }, // buttons in row 2
            new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton("inlineBtn3") }  // buttons in row 3
        }));
```

The message should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, but this code doesn't work for me, when I use it the robot doesn't send a response. i use try and catch but  it doesn't make any exception.

and the InlineKeyboardButton Class has no Any constructor with one that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Hi, is there a limit on the rows number in height of inlinekeyboard?